# parsing xml / xpath with splitted tags <dwd:Forecast dwd:elementName="FF">

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

All,

when parsing xml using lxml I am wondering how to find elements with such "double" tag-elements: 
`<dwd:Forecast dwd:elementName="PPPP">`

I even do not know how they are called so googling this is quite challenging.

The sample xml is like

```
<kml:Placemark>
    <kml:ExtendedData>
        <dwd:Forecast dwd:elementName="PPPP">
            <dwd:value>  101890.0
```

my sample code looks like this, but it does not return a value:

```
tree = etree.parse(open(kml_filename, "r"))
for p in tree.iter():
    # looking for <dwd:Forecast dwd:elementName="PPPP">
    if 'dwd:Forecast dwd:elementName="PPPP"' in tree.getpath(p):
        print (p.text)
```

ok, I am new to xml/xpath in python, maybe I got something wrong in general...

Comment: That first part in *"double"* tag name stands for *namespace*. You can ignore namespace while selecting element in `lxml` as `//*[name()="Placemark"]/*[name()="ExtendedData"]...` The same for attributes: `//*[name()="Forecast" and @*[name()="elementName" and .="PPPP"]]`

Comment: thanks, got it:
    `for df in tree.xpath('////*[name()="dwd:Forecast" and @*[name()="dwd:elementName" and .="PPPP"]]'):
        print (df.getchildren()[0].text)`